# Discrete Structures - Sets, graphing, and set builder notation help

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Have attempted to assess and produce answer, though teacher is very very particular, and doesn't give partial credit. I'm really not confident I can solve this. If anyone is great enough to illuminate my path.

Question - Let  $f$ be a function from $A = \{p,q,r\}$ to $B = \{s,t\}$ defined $f(p)=s$, $f(q)=s$, $f(r)=t$. Use set builder notation to describe the graph of $f$. Then, provide a set that lists all elements of the graph of $f$.

In accordance to the question, I can see that the element $A\{p\}$ corresponds to element $B\{s\}$, element $A\{q\}$ corresponds to $B\{s\}$, and element $A\{r\}$ corresponds to $B\{t\}$, only when applied to the function. I'm not, unfortunately, able to express such in set builder notation, though providing a set that lists all elements in graph $f$, sounds to be just a simple list reflecting the correspondence of each element. If you can provide any help, it be really appreciated!

EDIT - made question more contained, as per [user hardmath](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/3111/hardmath) tip

Just in case - [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUmjt.jpg)

Thank You!

Comment: It is pretty important to make the body of Questions as self-contained as possible, not relying on a link (to an image in this case, which may expire) to state the problem. See [the introductory note on posting mathematical expressions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) using $\LaTeX$.

Comment: understood, will try my best to do as such now, thank you

Comment: Frankly speaking, I do not see the difference between the two questions. The *graph* of $f$ is $\{ (p,s),(q,s), (r,t) \}$. How to "describe" it in a different way ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:A\to B$. If we denote the graph of $f$ by $G_f$, then using set builder notation we can describe it as follows: 
$$G_f=\{(x,f(x)) \mid x\in A\}.$$
To find the set that lists all elements in $G_f$ we note that the possible elements in the graph are: $$(p,f(p))=(p,s)$$ $$(q,f(q))=(q,s)$$ $$(r,f(r))=(r,t)$$ That is one for each element in $A$. Thus the set that lists them is: $$\{(p,s),(q,s),(r,t)\}.$$